# Weird documentation search behavior

Tags: bugs, documentation

I was typing a search in the docs and when I hit return I saw this:

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: This happen on me once in a while.If I restart my computer,it will not appeare again.

Answer (score 2):

It is and WRI is aware of it, I've already reported this after I faced it for:

> 1*^2

query.

> CASE:3838362
>   [...] It does appear as though our Documentation Center search tool doesn't handle the "1*^2" query very well. I have gone ahead and filed a report with our developers so that they can further investigate and look to address the issue. [...]

It seems that the problem is with `*` character, though it works standalone but with something more it breaks documentation search. `*1` etc.